# ICommand CanExecuteChanged causing memory leak

Tags: wpf

Given below is the abstract class and its implementation.CanExecuteChanged is causing the leak. It holds a strong refereence to the viewmodel. I am using Ants profiler. And it is clearly showing a leak with the handler.

```
 public abstract class AlwaysCanExecuteCommand : ICommand
 {
  #region ICommand Members

  /// <summary>
  /// The CanExecute command always return true, so this command can always be executed
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="parameter"></param>
  /// <returns>True; so command can always be executed</returns>
  public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
     return true;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Event that gets fired when this command's execution state changes
  /// </summary>
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


  /// <summary>
  /// Protected virtual function to raise the CanExecuteChanged event
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="e">Event argument</param>
  protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
     if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this, e);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Abstract Execute function, to always be overridden by derived classes to contain the
  /// code when command is executed
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="parameter">Parameter</param>
  public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
  #endregion
```

}

```
 public class EditCompanyProfileCommand : AlwaysCanExecuteCommand
 {
  private Organization _organization;
  private bool _isCustomerView;
  private readonly CommonFunctionService _commonFunctionService;

  /// <summary>
  /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EditCompanyProfileCommand"/> class.
  /// </summary>
  public EditCompanyProfileCommand(CommonFunctionService commonFunctionService)
  {
     _commonFunctionService = commonFunctionService;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or Sets if this view is for a Customer
  /// </summary>
  public bool IsCustomerView
  {
     get { return _isCustomerView; }
     set { _isCustomerView = value; }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The current Organization
  /// </summary>
  public Organization Organization
  {
     get { return _organization; }
     set { _organization = value; }
  }

  public override void Execute(object parameter)
  {
     IList list = parameter as IList;

     if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
     {
        CompanyProfile cachedCompanyProfile = null;
        DataRowView dataRowView = list[0] as DataRowView;
        if (dataRowView != null)
        {
           Guid companyId = (Guid)dataRowView[dataRowView.Row.ItemArray.Length - 1];
           if (companyId != null)
              cachedCompanyProfile = CBC.Instance.GetFullyRealizedCompanyProfile(companyId);
        }
        else
           cachedCompanyProfile = list[0] as CompanyProfile;

        if (cachedCompanyProfile != null)
        {
          ....
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: You need to provide more details.  Why do you think you've got a memory leak?  What tool is telling you this?  What objects are being held, etc...

Comment: I am using ANTS memory profiler. It is showing a leak in the CanExecuteEventHandler. The handler is holding a strong reference to the viewmodel.

After i changed the implementation as follows the leak was gone,
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
      {
         add { }
         remove { }
      }

      protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs e)
      {
         
      }

Comment: Does your ViewModel subscribe to `CanExecuteChanged` on the command?

Comment: No my viewmodel does not subscribe to it.

Comment: You need to show your real code - not the abstract class, but the concrete one, as well.

Comment: I have edited my post which includes the concrete class.

Comment: Something has to be subscribing to CanExecuteChanged, or your profiler is reporting a false reference - tough to know which is the problem from what you've posted

Comment: The profiler can't be reporting a false reference because i verified this by other methods (forcing gc through code, memory was not reclaimed).

Comment: Thanks Dan. But it is not very clear how i should raise CanExecuteChanged.